# Firebird after insert trigger - insert a timestamp to inserted row

Tags: firebird, database-trigger

I have a field which is "timestamp" type, called "inserted_when".
How can I update this field (insert a timestamp) after insert (so it only applies to selected inserted record) ? By means of a trigger of course...
edit :

I tried this but cant seem to make uncommented part to work.

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_INSERT FOR MYTABLE
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 1
AS
BEGIN
      UPDATE MYTABLE 
      SET MYTABLE.inserted_when = current_timestamp;

   ---- where mytable.ID = Inserted.ID
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the record being inserted, you need to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, not an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. The values of the row to be inserted can be accessed (and updated) through the `NEW` context variable (there is also an `OLD` context variable, but that isn't relevant in a insert trigger). Note that Firebird triggers fire per row.

So you need to change your trigger to:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE_INSERT_MYTABLE FOR MYTABLE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
      NEW.inserted_when = current_timestamp;
END
```

Note that the `OLD` context variable is never modifiable, and the `NEW` context variable is only modifiable in a `BEFORE` trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You can only update the fields which are to be updated in a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

In the trigger, you can do:

```
new.inserted_when = current_timestamp;
```

The trigger is called for each record updated.

If you're doing `UPDATE MYTABLE` in `AFTER UPDATE`, you may end up in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

or just have a default value for the inserted_when column of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

no trigger needed then